# Ошибка при компиляции в gradlew

Tags: java

Всем привет. Я делаю свой Packet Hack для чита в Minecraft. При компиляции мода в gradlew столкнулся с проблемой:

> F:\cheats minecraft\custom\build\sources\java\INFO\mcheli\wrapper\W_Blocks.java:11: error: cannot find symbol

```
public class W_Blocks extends Blocks {

        ^
  symbol:   constructor Blocks()
  location: class Blocks

код класса W_Blocks:

package mcheli.wrapper;

import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;

public class W_Blocks extends Blocks {

}
```

Я не разбираюсь в Java, может быть ошибка в синтаксисе, кто может помочь?

Comment: 1. Пользуйся форматированием кода. 2. Ошибка непонятна.

Comment: чем лучше отформатировать? я редактирую код в notepad++

Comment: Нет, на сайте отформатировать, ибо у тебя он коряво отображается. Сам посмотри, что у тебя и как должно выглядеть: `System.out.println("Hello world");` видимо ошибка твоя связана, что файл не может найти нужный. Проверь путь. Вот ошибка: cheats minecraft - у тебя в пути пробел. Я тебе дал ответ, если он был полезен, то отметь его. Если нет, то будем продолжать искать выход.

Comment: При компиляции других классов, этой проблемы не возникало. А поверь, их там много :D

Comment: Мне кажется, что W_Blocks ищет какую то либу, но найти не может и я не могу понять что ему нужно

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка связана с тем, что находится пробел в пути, а конкретно:

> cheats minecraft

```
F:\cheats minecraft\custom\build\sources\java\INFO\mcheli\wrapper\W_Blocks.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
```

Comment: При компиляции других классов, этой проблемы не возникало. А поверь, их там много :D

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась удалением из кода строки extends Blocks
Конечный код
package mcheli.wrapper;

import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;

public class W_Blocks{
}
Не знаю как это повлияет на функционал мода, но надеюсь это поможет

Answer (score 0):

Если не определять конструктор, Java сама добавит конструктор по умолчанию, вызывающий super(). Ошибка говорит, что в классе Blocks нет конструктора без параметров.
Для исправления ошибки надо явно определить конструктор класса W_Blocks.